# HashAlgorithms in CoreCLR

Tags: asp.net-core, coreclr

I'm trying use this [class](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/creating-salted-hash-values-in-c/) in my coreclr project but I can't seem to find the correct package for SHA256Managed. I have tried using System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.0.0-beta-23409" but it doesn't contain the implementation of SHA2565Managed. Are there any other alternative for computing hash values in coreclr?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `SHA256.Create()` from namespace `System.Security.Cryptography`

*(Assembly: `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`)*

```
using (var algorithm = SHA256.Create())
{
    // Create the at_hash using the access token returned by CreateAccessTokenAsync.
    var hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.AccessToken));

    // Note: only the left-most half of the hash of the octets is used.
    // See http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeIDToken
    identity.AddClaim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.AtHash, Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(hash, 0, hash.Length / 2));
}
```

Comment: It's actually in `System.Security.Cryptography`, not `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`.

Comment: @Pavel the package name is [`System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/) and the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize it was a NuGet package.

Comment: FYI it's not a NuGet package. It's part of .Net Core.

Comment: @Kris in 2.0, yes: it’s included in the .NET Standard 2.0 assemblies and ships with the .NET Core 2.0 runtime. In 1.x, you had to reference the NuGet package I mentioned.

Comment: I ran into a problem on .NET Core with PlatformNotSupportedException.
Fixed it with (HashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("SHA-256"); https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22626